# What features does RX.Component class provide over React.Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactxp

The documentation around Microsoft's recently released [ReactXP](https://microsoft.github.io/reactxp) doesn't have much information about the `RX.Component` class at the moment.

Here's an example from the documentation:

```
class HelloWorld extends RX.Component<void, void> {
    render() {
        return <RX.Text>Hello World</RX.Text>;
    }
}
```

1. What are the features offered by `RX.Component` over `React.Component`?
2. How does it influence the life-cycle of the base `Component` class?

This is an important consideration for me because best practices for React components typically encourage [composition over inheritance](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#so-what-about-inheritance), except for very basic scenarios like `PureComponent`. Would the features provided by `RX.Component` justify the inheritance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe it's the same:

https://github.com/Microsoft/reactxp/blob/master/src/web/ReactXP.ts#L131

Maybe they just want to make everything under the `RX` namespace so you only need to `import RX = require('reactxp');`